# Taxi in suburbs/mountains of Italy

Tags: italy, transportation, taxis

What are best and safe ways/webs/apps to order a taxi with a price in advance in Italian mountains/suburbs where there are no bus connections and one does not speak Italian?
Example: Bone – Usellières

Comment: Can I ask those suggesting (opposing) reasons for closing to be more specific what am I supposed to change? 
– Not specific?: Every country has its reliable taxi companies or platform that do not operate elsewhere and I'd like to get this knowledge from the locals. How can I be more specific? 
– Too specific?: How can I generalize the question about reliable ways of transportation when there are no public buses?

Answer (score 3):

Search for the nearest village/town that has taxi services.  Phone them and tell them when and where you want to take a taxi.  You will probably have to speak Italian (in Valle d'Aoste, you might be able to use French) and will probably have to negotiate a price.  You cannot expect those taxi drivers to be bookable with a website or smartphone app.

If you are staying in a hotel, the hotel may be able to help you.  If the nearest town or village has a tourist office, the tourist office may be able to help you.  You may have to pay a premium if the nearest town is far away.  If you are further off the beaten track, you're on your own.

From Bone to Usellières I would walk or hitch-hike.

It will be much easier to take a taxi /to/ the mountains than /from/ the mountains.

Comment: Good point that it will be easier to get to the mountains than back. And good point with the language.. .